Regular conic $\mathcal{C}$ in $\mathbb{P}_{2}({\mathbb{C}})$ with equation $XAX^T$; tangent lines to conic
Given a non-null row matrix $D$ the line of homogeneous equation $DX^T=0$ is tangent to $\mathcal{C}$ iff $DA^{-1}D^T=0$; where $XAX^T=0$ is the matrix form of the regular conic.
Furthermore, given $P \in  \mathbb{P}_{2}({\mathbb{C}})$ and $l_0,l_1$ two distinct lines with homogeneous equations $D_0X^T=0;D_1X^T=0$, we have that a line belonging to the pencil of lines passing through $P$ has homogeneous equation $(sD_0+tD_1)X^T=0; (s,t) \neq (0,0)$
Using the result above; such a line is tangent to $\mathcal{C}$ iff
$$s^2D_0A^{-1}D_0^T+2stD_0A^{-1}D_1^T+t^2D_1A^{-1}D_1^T=0$$
And now, my goal is to show that if $P \in \mathcal{C}$, there's only one tangent to $\mathcal{C}$ passing through $P$, in other case, there are two tangent lines to $\mathcal{C}$ passing through $P$
If there were two tangent lines, we could obtain $2stD_0A^{-1}D_1=0$ using $D_0,D_1$ homogeneous triples for such lines, but this doesn't seem helpful. Any suggestions?
EDIT: I guess that the existence of two tangent lines is related with $D_0A^{-1}D_1^T\neq0$
